# near-real time search on top of solr

Tags: solr, hbase, real-time, solrcloud, real-time-data

We have a live system and we're using solr (v4.3.1) to index and serve data (and analysis results). As it's live, plenty of data is arriving at each moment and we need to somehow store it and show to end user with analytical results. To show raw data with analysis results (summary of data, in other words), we use range and facet queries to query solr and the performance is satisfactory. However, as data receives continuously, solr does not seem to be a good solution for storing/indexing data instantly (May be on [future relases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching)). I'm planning to use hbase as a buffer in front of solr but I'm not sure how I can handle facet/range queries on hbase.

How can I handle this situation /w hbase? Any ideas to make things faster is also well appreciated!

Thanks all.

Comment: What exact issues does Solr have? Long search times, slow for changes to appear?

Comment: well, if you try to index documents with i.e. 15 minutes interval on a solr instance with a few million documents, cache warmup process takes a while and queries are queued until solr finishes its internal operations. After it finishes and able to response within a sensible time, new documents arrive and the whole waiting process starts again. Maybe a front-cache solr instance could be defined, but not sure about scalability and performance. I'd like to know community experiences on that issue.

Comment: Adding documents should not prevent the immediate execution of queries. What internal operations are you waiting for?

Comment: we' re using solr 4.3.1 and indexing new documents -may be not prevent but- delay execution of queries. Well, that would be wrong if I say that queries wait until indexing is finished, but response time increases drastically.

Comment: Maybe your CPU is limiting. You could try spread the document additions over the 15min as opposed to in bursts.

Comment: I'll give a shot, but I don't think so. Same problem occurs on 8-noded solr cloud (w/ a 3 noded zookeeper ensemble)